# Executar Modal Code Behind ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Estou tentando executar um modal pelo ASP.NET e consegui;

Usando o Script

```
  <div id="mymodals" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">
                        <asp:Label Text="" ID="lbl_errortitulo" runat="server" /></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label Text="" ID="lbl_errormsg" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Entendi</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_execute" onclick="Mensagem()" >Executar</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Mensagem() {
            $('#mymodals').modal({ show: true });
        }          
    </script>
```

Porém, se eu coloque em um asp:Button creio que o PostBack faça-o "bugar"...

A duvida é, precisava executar este modal pelo code-behind quando caísse no "catch", usando;

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), 
                      "mymodals", 
                      "Mensagem();", 
                      true
);
```

Só que, não executa, creio que seja o postback!?

Comment: Os dados são fixos?

Comment: Como assim fixos?

Comment: Mostrar o Modal ??? e ??? porque se for Javascript não precisa passar para o BackEnd

Comment: Então, queria que chamasse o Modal caso caísse no Catch do bloco Try

Comment: Não tem nada na sua pergunta que mostre `try` `catch`!

Comment: A duvida é, precisava executar este modal pelo code-behind quando caísse no "catch", usando;

Comment: A sua duvida não é clara, não tem catch, não tem code-behind na pergunta, só tem um código da pagina `aspx`(trecho) e um função em javascript ... ou seja, reformule a sua pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), key: "script", script: "<script>$('#mymodals').modal('show');</script> ", addScriptTags: false);
```

Comment: Exatamente o que esse código faz e como poderia ser a solução para a pergunta?(Não responda com um comentário para mim, *edite e melhore a sua resposta*)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui desta forma:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button Text="Abrir Modal" ID="btn_button" runat="server" OnClick="btn_button_Click1" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Eu não sei o proposito, falta informação, você não resolveu o problema talvez acabou criando outro, se sabe o que é UpdatePanel ? então ... cuidado com soluções assim eu acho que nem precisa disso, mas, falta contexto na sua pergunta.

Comment: Assim, eu precisava executar um Modal caso o bloco Try entrasse no Catch (quando gerasse um erro) apenas para mostrar ao usuário que deu erro, porém, precisava fazer isso lá do Code-Behind, só que, simplesmente não executava usando             ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Modal", "Mensagem()", true);

Comment: O que seria esse "outro problema" que eu possa ter criado?

Comment: Então você colocou isso no UpdatePanel que é Ajax resumindo ... mas, precisa? outra coisa em nenhum momento tem try catch no sua pergunta, aonde está isso, na parte de programação ?

Comment: Sim, basicamente o asp:Button iria executar uma função de cadastro dentro de um bloco TryCatch, e se caísse no Catch, gostaria de chamar o Modal através do JavaScript informando qual erro deu, entendeu? porém não estava conseguindo executar o function do javascript no Code-Behind, e dessa forma consegui